# Fixing Cross-Domain Requests in IE8

Tags: jquery, ajax, internet-explorer-8, cors, crossdomain-request.js

I'm trying to modify some existing code that is breaking in IE8. From what I've read online, this is a common problem involving XDomainRequest and XMLHttpRequest.

I've not worked with AJAX in this fashion before, so I'm at a compete loss of what to do here. The code is as follows: (I've replaced sensitive information in brackets "[[" and "]]" with arbitrary variable names to identify where each one is used):

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

    var base_url = '[[BASE_URL_1]]';   // DTRT for ajax requests (CORS over HTTP by default)
    if (document.location.protocol == "https:") {
        base_url = '[[BASE_URL_2]]';    // The proxy script that lets us do secure cross-domain AJAX requests
    }
    var classSpec = '$class_spec';

    $('#[[ID_1]]').empty().addClass('loading'); // loading gif
    $('#[[ID_2]]').empty().addClass('loading');

    $.ajax( {
         type: "GET",
          url: base_url + '[[URL_1]]' + classSpec + '[[URL_2]]',
      success: function (data) { $('[[ID_2]]').html(data).removeClass('loading'); }
    } );

    $.ajax( {
         type: "GET",
          url: base_url + '[[URL_1]' + classSpec + '[[URL_3]]',
      success: function (data) { $('[[ID+1]]').html(data).removeClass('loading'); initialize(); }
    } );

});
```

How can I modify this code to include support for IE8?

Comment: Have you added the correct Access-Control-Allow-Origin headers on the server your talking to ? XDR must be explicitly allowed on the other server.

Comment: @Robert thanks for the pointer. I am not sure, since I'm new to this type of problem altogether. I realize there's a lot I need to get a grasp on before I can solve the issue. I will try to pinpoint the server headers and see what I can figure out from there.

Comment: @Robert Perl controller contains the following line: ```$c->response->header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin" => $server);```

Answer (score 1):

To do cross domain requests you will probably need to check the following

1. jQuery.support.cors = true;
2. crossDomain =  true;

   - http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/
3. Access-Control-Allow-Origin headers

   - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd573303%28v=vs.85%29.aspx
   - https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/HTTP/Access_control_CORS

1 & 2

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

    var base_url = '[[BASE_URL_1]]';   // DTRT for ajax requests (CORS over HTTP by default)
    if (document.location.protocol == "https:") {
        base_url = '[[BASE_URL_2]]';    // The proxy script that lets us do secure cross-domain AJAX requests
    }
    var classSpec = '$class_spec';

    $('#[[ID_1]]').empty().addClass('loading'); // loading gif
    $('#[[ID_2]]').empty().addClass('loading');

    jQuery.support.cors = true;
    $.ajax(
    {
        crossDomain: true,
        type: "GET",
        url: base_url + '[[URL_1]]' + classSpec + '[[URL_2]]',
        success: function (data) { $('[[ID_2]]').html(data).removeClass('loading'); }
    } );

    $.ajax(
    {
        crossDomain: true,
        type: "GET",
        url: base_url + '[[URL_1]' + classSpec + '[[URL_3]]',
        success: function (data) { $('[[ID+1]]').html(data).removeClass('loading'); initialize(); }
    } );
});
```

3) Actually requires you to have access to the server you want to talk to. Basically the distant server says to the browser: Hey i allow these domains to do XDR requests, if you are not one of them ..please don't send any. *(personally this is the craziest security scenario i have ever seen ..since it's up to the requester, to refrain itself from making requests to domains that don't want requests from him. That really sounds secure, hein !)*.

So if you are on server site1.com and want to XDR to site2.com, then site2.com must return a header like

Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *

or

Access-Control-Allow-Origin: site1.com

When working with IIS servers, you will probably also need to supply: Access-Control-Allow-Methods

---

The above normally applies to ALL browsers, not just IE8, for IE8 specifics have a look here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2010/05/13/xdomainrequest-restrictions-limitations-and-workarounds.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I recommend trying out this library: 
https://github.com/MoonScript/jQuery-ajaxTransport-XDomainRequest which

> Implements automatic Cross Origin Resource Sharing support using the XDomainRequest object for IE8 and IE9 when using the $.ajax function in jQuery 1.5+"

It does have the same limitations as XDomainRequest namely:

> In order to use XDomainRequest in Internet Explorer, the request must be:
>
> - Only GET or POST
>
>   - When POSTing, the data will always be sent with a Content-Type of text/plain
> - Only HTTP or HTTPS
>
>   - Protocol must be the same scheme as the calling page
> - Always asynchronous

It looks like you are checking for matching protocols so you should be covered there.